# Plotly surface plot is glitchy and parts flicker in and out

Tags: python, graph, plotly

I'm trying to plot a surface in plotly, and it does plot, but parts of the surface flicker in and out, and I'm not quite sure how to fix it. Below are two images that will hopefully help to illustrate what I'm talking about. If I rotate the plot, I can get the full surface to appear, but it's only showing up about 50% of the time, with the other times parts of the graph cut out. It seems like it's only the lower values in the plot that are cutting out, and also it seems like the higher the value, the more likely it is to be there all the time. So for example the yellow peaks are there all of the time, the orange are there almost all the time, the purple peaks are there about 60% of the time, and then the lowest parts are there 50% of the time.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out there was some setting in the default template that was used when creating the surface plot. By setting the template to use no template with the following command, the flickering goes away

```
fig.update_layout(template='none')
```