# Plotly surface plot flickering

Tags: python, graph, plotly

This is related to a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72872642/plotly-surface-plot-is-glitchy-and-parts-flicker-in-and-out) , but I have it narrowed down a bit. If at least one of the axis is turned on, then the flicker happens like below. I'm turning off the axis with the following setting

```
fig.update_scenes(xaxis_visible=False)
```

[image]

if I turn off the the visibility for all axis though, I don't get a flicker.

[image]

I assume there's one of the axis settings that is causing the flickering... but I'm not sure which one it is. I'd like to keep the axis titles and and values, but I'm fine turning other things off... I'm just not quite sure which one would do it. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't confirm the event since you don't provide any data, but I see from the image that the default template seems to be affected, so would it be possible to improve the situation if the template is not used as follows? `fig.update_layout(template='none',....)`

Comment: This did the trick! I was never specifying a template, and didn't know that was a thing, but  not using a template makes the flickering go away. Thanks a bunch for this! if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented, it seems that it is the template that is affected. The questioner ran the data on which the question is based and did not see any flicker. By setting the template to no template, the 3D graph is displayed with the axis scales preserved.

```
fig.update_layout(template='none',...)
```